# Is it possible to import/export EPiServer Community data (entity and attribute)?

Tags: import, export, episerver, episerver-6

I'm working on EPiServer Community 4 project. In development phase, I setup some predefine entity data (add some clubs, some forums, ...) and create/assign attribute to them.

How can I export those data (entity data and its attribute/attribute value) and import later? (I will import when installing my product for customer).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You however could use something called [Community Attribute Builder](http://world.episerver.com/Blogs/Valdis-Iljuconoks/Dates/2012/6/Community-Attribute-Builder-final/).

That will sync your entity attributes from code to target Community site.
However for content (clubs, polls, etc) there is unfortunately no such a functionality to export/import.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this manually in the database, or create a custom code that can read the data and store it. There is no built in feature for exporting/importing community data.